# How to upload it to server?

Tags: java, web-services

i want to upload the sound file (.ogg) in server.

But it should write into the server concurrently while recording.

My program it gets the input as PCM_SIGNED audio encoding

though its the raw format i have to encode and upload it to server

As for now  i employed vorbis encoder to convert the raw format to .ogg format its working

nicely.But it should concurrently write into the server.

Thanks

krishna

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea what you're asking. Can you please clarify the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you connect to the server?

- If you are using FTP here is some help: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-2003/jw-0404-ftp.html?page=1
- If you are using HTTP here is a file upload example: http://www.example-code.com/java/upload_asynchExample.asp